# Prefer +ing, correct answer

Tags: grammaticality

Which one is correct?

> I prefer sleeping rather than going out and **live**.

or

> I prefer sleeping rather than going out and **living**.

Answer (score 1):

"Sleep" is not the present *continuous* form of the verb, neither is "live". You are comparing two things that people *do*, so both verbs need to be in the same form - "sleeping" and "living".

Also, we use "prefer" with the word "to" because you are *comparing* two things.

Your sentence should be:

> I prefer sleeping *to* going out and living.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion, but the argument is wrong. There is no "present continuous" anywhere in the examples. There is an "-ing" form, which can be used to construct that form, but in the absence of a form of "be", that form is not present. I would call all the _-ing_ forms in the examples "gerunds".